# Unable to access AJAX url with requests, BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to read the data of a table, which is an onclick ajax event of the following [webpage](http://www.hidrografico.pt/boias-ondografo.php)

The event initiates if you click the + sign to the right of the Tabelas tab, at the bootom of the page.

Using the FireBug (for example) from my browser y can optain the ajax url from the XHR tab of the NET section.

The url is valid and the browser picks it up and shows it.

My script:

```
 import requests

 urls="http://www.hidrografico.pt/components/com_products/scripts/server/data_getestactable.php"

 headers = {
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0',
'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
 }

 s = requests.Session()
 s.post(urls)

 content = s.post(urls, headers=headers)

 print content.content
```

The output for this gives:

```
Direct access to this file is prohibited.
```

So its seems there is no direct access to the url although if I paste the url in my browser I can see the table, which is in source code.

I dont know if I am missing something or the page in itself blocks any direct attempt of readinig.

I tried through the main webpage to access the table using BeautifulSoup(text) and then blabla.find(class,{'id':blabla}) and then blabla.findAll() but it gives back the

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

because de attribute class 'find' finds nothing.

I would appreciate any kind of help and guidance to tackle this hurdle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the **POST** parameters you will find that you need to send  `estid=4&param=1` and this will work only if you have the right cookies which you can get by sending a **GET** requests to the front page.

```
import requests


# Prepare the session that will store the cookies.
s = requests.Session()
# Get the cookies
s.get("http://www.hidrografico.pt/boias-ondografo.php")

table_url = "http://www.hidrografico.pt/components/com_products/scripts/server/data_getestactable.php"    
# Prepare the parameters
payload = { "estid": "4",
        "param": "1" 
        }
r = s.post(table_url, data=payload)
print r.text
```

Comment: Wow !!! thanks a lot!!! knew about the cookies but had nt think about the post variables.
Many thanks for your help.